# Anybody got huggingface transformers to work in a Conda env?

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, conda, huggingface-transformers

The title. At this point I basically tried all combinations of TF 2.0, 2.1, tensorflow-gpu (both 2.1 and 2.0) and the latest huggingface build. Plus creating new environments from scratch for each try.

I can either:

- Install tensorflow-gpu (2.0 or 2.1) -> TF does find my GPU, but then huggingface cannot find a single TF model. For example, I can `import AutoModel` just fine, but I cannot `import TFAutoModel` (error: `ImportError: cannot import name 'TFAutoModel' from 'transformers' (unknown location)`). This happens with everything TF* that I tried.

OR

- Install tensorflow (2.0 or 2.1) -> TF does NOT find my GPU, but I can `import TFAutoModel` without an issue.

I have also installed the required CUDA and cuDNN versions and have a GPU with enough compute power yadda yadda.

TL;DR: How to get huggingface TF models to work with TF GPU?

Comment: What is your OS?

Comment: Dang I forgot to mention... I'm on Win10, fully up-to-date.

Comment: How did you check wether the GPU is used or not, I tried installing in a fresh env and at least your import works

Comment: I have the same error on MACOS 11.2. conda create -n tf tensorflow creates a python 3.7.2 environment. Then pip install huggingface.

Still get "cannot import name 'TFAutoModelForSequenceClassification' from 'transformers' (unknown location)"

Answer (score 0):

On my windows machine, I could simply do:

```
conda create -n tf tensorflow-gpu
conda activate tf
conda install -c huggingface
```

This installed tensorflow-gpu version 2.3.0 and transformers 4.2.2

I could then run one of the sample codes from [their website](https://huggingface.co/transformers/task_summary.html):

```
(tf) C:\> python
Python 3.8.5 (default, Sep  3 2020, 21:29:08) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from transformers import pipeline
>>> nlp = pipeline("sentiment-analysis")
Downloading: 100%|██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 629/629 [00:00<00:00, 180kB/s]
Downloading: 100%|███████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 268M/268M [00:21<00:00, 12.5MB/s]
2021-02-03 08:59:08.884730: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN)to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2021-02-03 08:59:09.109504: W tensorflow/python/util/util.cc:348] Sets are not currently considered sequences, but this may change in the future, so consider avoiding using them.
Some layers from the model checkpoint at distilbert-base-uncased-finetuned-sst-2-english were not used when initializing TFDistilBertModel: ['pre_classifier', 'dropout_19', 'classifier']
- This IS expected if you are initializing TFDistilBertModel from the checkpoint of a model trained on another task or with another architecture (e.g. initializing a BertForSequenceClassification model from a BertForPreTraining model).
- This IS NOT expected if you are initializing TFDistilBertModel from the checkpoint of a model that you expect to be exactly identical (initializing a BertForSequenceClassification model from a BertForSequenceClassification model).
All the layers of TFDistilBertModel were initialized from the model checkpoint at distilbert-base-uncased-finetuned-sst-2-english.
If your task is similar to the task the model of the checkpoint was trained on, you can already use TFDistilBertModel for predictions without further training.
Downloading: 100%|████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 232k/232k [00:00<00:00, 528kB/s]
Some layers from the model checkpoint at distilbert-base-uncased-finetuned-sst-2-english were not used when initializing TFDistilBertForSequenceClassification: ['dropout_19']
- This IS expected if you are initializing TFDistilBertForSequenceClassification from the checkpoint of a model trained on another task or with another architecture (e.g. initializing a BertForSequenceClassification model from a BertForPreTraining model).
- This IS NOT expected if you are initializing TFDistilBertForSequenceClassification from the checkpoint of a model that you expect to be exactly identical (initializing a BertForSequenceClassification model from a BertForSequenceClassification model).
Some layers of TFDistilBertForSequenceClassification were not initialized from the model checkpoint at distilbert-base-uncased-finetuned-sst-2-english and are newly initialized: ['dropout_38']
You should probably TRAIN this model on a down-stream task to be able to use it for predictions and inference.
>>> result = nlp("I hate you")[0]
>>> print(f"label: {result['label']}, with score: {round(result['score'], 4)}")
label: NEGATIVE, with score: 0.9991
>>> result = nlp("I love you")[0]
>>> print(f"label: {result['label']}, with score: {round(result['score'], 4)}")
label: POSITIVE, with score: 0.9999
```

As well as the import you have mentioned:

```
>>> from transformers import TFAutoModel
>>>
```

Comment: Have you checked whether GPU is used?